# How to convert from FILETIME to Ruby time and vice-versa

Tags: ruby

MSDN defines FILETIME as

> 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals
>   since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

How to convert between FILETIME and Ruby Time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Time
  # Convert the time to the FILETIME format, a 64-bit value representing the
  # number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).
  def wtime
    self.to_i * 10000000 + (self.tv_nsec/100.0).round + 116444736000000000
  end

  # Create a time object from the FILETIME format, a 64-bit value representing
  # the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).
  def self.from_wtime(wtime)
    Time.at((wtime - 116444736000000000) / 10000000,
            ((wtime - 116444736000000000) % 10000000)/10.0)
  end
end
```

Credit: [Christopher Sexton](http://www.codeography.com/2009/05/20/working-with-filetime-in-ruby.html), with fixes for nanosecond/100 precision by me.

Usage:

```
wtime = 131172192735329876
#=> 131172192735329876

t = Time.from_wtime(wtime)
#=> 2016-09-01 12:01:13 -0400

t.wtime
#=> 131172192735329876

t.wtime == wtime
#=> true

Time.now.wtime
#=> 131520319622603520
```

Comment: Thanks for the mention, that was a nice surprise while I was looking through new questions.

Comment: @csexton haha .. small world! I actually searched you in here to mention you, but a search on your name didn't find you. Thanks for the snipped! I needed more than a second precision so I figured I should share my edit. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Based on your code, but slightly shorter:

```
require 'time'

class Time
  def self.from_wtime(wtime)
    Time.utc(1601) + wtime.quo(10_000_000)
  end

  def wtime
    ((to_r - Time.utc(1601).to_r) * 10_000_000).to_i
  end
end
```